# .FLAC having the same bitrate as decoded .WAV

Tags: flac

I got a .flac file (17.9MB, 24bit/96kHz) from the Internet and I am unable to figure out why it feels like there is no compression in the file at all. The decoded .wav(15.9MB, 24bit/96kHz) is a bit smaller than the .flac, even after stripping away the metadata.

I then re-encoded (libFLAC 1.3.2) the .flac and it indeed compressed down to more than half of the original. I am curious of what exactly happened to the first .flac file (libFLAC 1.3.1, according to mediainfo)

I uploaded the two .flac (total 24MB) to [Github](https://github.com/pendechosen/unusual_flac_file). I will swiftly remove the repository after having the question solved.

**Update 1**:
I am surprised to find out that the .flac file and along with other .flac i have downloaded, they all seem to have the same bitrate despite their difference in duration. If specifying a constant bitrate for encoding is not possible, then I wonder *is there any way to disable compression in the encoder which can explain their constant bitrate. The decoded .wav has the same bitrate as the original .flac somehow.*

**Update 2**:
Title changed from ".FLAC having a greater size than decoded .WAV" to ".FLAC having the same bitrate as decoded .WAV"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently what I was looking into is Uncompressed FLAC. Such encoding can be done with tools like [dBpoweramp Music Converter](http://www.audiostream.com/content/dbpoweramps-flac-lossless-uncompressed-wish-come-true#fZu7lGWHcs39zV13.97) or XRECODE3.

From [here](http://www.computeraudiophile.com/f11-software/using-uncompressed-flac-conversion-w-eac-17530/), I have obtained a command line for libFLAC to achieve a similar result:

```
flac --disable-constant-subframes --disable-fixed-subframes --no-seektable -l 0 -b 4608 -V input.wav -o output.flac
```

Repository deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the original .FLAC file has a bitrate of over twice the re-encoded .FLAC file (4943Kbps vs 2216Kbps).

By doing some simple maths, we can calculate the maximum bitrate needed to achieve a lossless, uncompressed audio file:

`96000 Samples per Second * 24 Bits per Sample = 2304000 Bits per Second (2304Kbps)`

We can see that the original file was forced to encode with a much higher bitrate than was needed. Re-encoding the file using normal settings should achieve a much more reasonable bitrate for the file type, therefore resulting in a smaller overall file.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i am not sure what [encoding options](https://xiph.org/flac/documentation_tools_flac.html#encoding_options) i can use to force encode with a higher bitrate, or arbitrary bitrate if possible.

Comment: @Pendechosen I am not sure how to specify an exact bitrate, but it could have been a combination of encoding options that did not play well with the file. In terms of compression amounts, you can set a preset between 0 and 8, or tinker with the `-l` `-b` and `-r` flags. This is likely an error in the original encoding.

Comment: I am surprised to find out that the .flac file and along with other .flac i have downloaded, they all seem to have the same bitrate despite their difference in duration. If specifying a constant bitrate for encoding is not possible, then I wonder is there any way to disable compression in the encoder which can explain their constant bitrate. The decoded .wav has the same bitrate as the original .flac somehow.